# Can't Follow the Algebra in a Estimator MSE Comparison

Tags: self-study, expected-value, estimators

Little bit of background - working through some maths and stats autodidactically. I simply can not follow the algebra of the following worked example comparing the MSE of two estimators.

I can not reconcile the following equality:

$$\sum_{i=0}^n X_i^2 =\sum_{i=0}^n ({X_i}^2 -{\bar{X}}^2)+n{\bar{X}}^2$$

I tried to work through the derivation myself and ended up with the following:

\begin{align}
\sum_{i=0}^n X_i^2 \\
&=\sum_{i=0}^n X_i^2 -2n\bar{X}X_i+{n\bar{X}}^2+2n\bar{X}X_i-{n\bar{X}}^2 \\
&=\sum_{i=0}^n ({X_i}^2 -2\bar{X}X_i+{\bar{X}}^2)+2n\bar{X}X_i-{n\bar{X}}^2 \\
&=\sum_{i=0}^n ({X_i}^2 -{\bar{X}}^2)+2n\bar{X}X_i-{n\bar{X}}^2
\end{align}

If someone from this wonderful community could point out where I have gone wrong I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yor equality is a trivial identity:
$$\sum_i({X_i}^2 -{\bar{X}}^2)+n{\bar{X}}^2=\sum_i X_i^2-n\bar{X}^2+n\bar{X}^2=\sum_i X_i^2$$

As far I can guess, your equality actually is
$$\sum_i(X_i-\overline{X})^2=\sum_i X_i^2 - n\bar{X}^2\quad\text{or}\quad
\sum_i X_i^2=\sum_i(X_i-\overline{X})^2+n\bar{X}^2$$
and what you are missing is
\begin{align*}
\sum_i(\dots-2X_i\bar{X}+\dots)&=\sum_i(\dots)-2\left(\sum_iX_i\right)\bar{X}+\sum_i(\dots)\\
&=\sum_i(\dots)-2(n\bar{X})\bar{X}+\sum_i(\dots)
\end{align*}
HTH

Comment: ahh - the $\bar{X}$ is constant and can come out. Thank you so much Sergio :)

Comment: You are welcome!